# What does ping -l mean?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, ping

Can anyone help me in understanding this command?

```
ping -l 1 google.com
```

I don't see the difference between `ping google.com` and `ping -l 1 google.com` as they both ping Google continuously.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it just gives a "command not found" error. Probably yo mean `ping -l1 google.com`. Case matters ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `man ping` for more info:

```
 -l preload
              If preload is specified, ping sends that many packets not  wait‐
              ing for reply.  Only the super-user may select preload more than
              3.
```